# What vim setting determines the amount of indentation change by pressing > or < (greater than or less than)?

Tags: indentation

For me the <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> are set to 8 spaces. I would like them to be set to 4 spaces. What setting corresponds to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by `shiftwidth`

```
set sw=4
```